# Animation not triggering rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I have the following React Native code. I am running it on Android but haven't tried other devices. When it runs, I push the button to run the animation and can see that the reference value is being updated and printed to the console in my addListener callback. But it seems to never trigger a re-rendering of my component even though endAngle is being updated. So, my component renders one time and then never changes with the animation. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

```
export default AnimatedDonutWrapper = (props) => {
  let AnimatedDonut = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(DonutChart);
  var endAngle = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.1)).current;

  endAngle.addListener((data) => {
    console.log(
      'data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' ' + JSON.stringify(endAngle),
    );
  });

  function animate() {
    Animated.timing(endAngle, {
      toValue: 2 * Math.PI,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{flex: 1, justifyDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <AnimatedDonut
          data={[2, 4, 6, 8]}
          chartTranslate={[useWindowDimensions().width / 2, 150]}
          innerRadius={70}
          outerRadius={100}
          startAngle={0}
          endAngle={endAngle}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, width: '50%'}}>
          <Button title="Refresh" color="red" onPress={animate} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, right off the bat I was getting warnings about needing to set useNativeDriver to true, so I did that. By the time I got the code "working" the useNativeDriver: True was keeping it from functioning. I switched it to false and then my animation ran fine. I need to look into this more to better understand what's going on, but it is running now.